# Is there a way to make a Google App Script installable?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have written a Google App Script for Gmail.

However I want this to be made available to everyone, and Google App Scripts may be hard for the illiterate to do so.

I was thinking of creating a web app in Google App Script, but is it even possible to create an installment script to help install a Google App Script?

To automate it for the normal user, so they can use the script?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look and creating an [addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview).